# kile 2.1.2 in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: kile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I read that kile was upgraded to version 2.1.2 which might have a live preview feature included. So I wanted to install it on ubuntu 11.10 but I don't seem to have much luck. I added the ppa for kile/stable but it doesn't work. This is what i get after sudo apt-get update:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kile/stable/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kile/stable/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

and a similar one for binary 386 I can't post because i am a new user and i can only have 2 hyper links.

Is there a way to install the newest version of kile in ubuntu 11.10? I would like to avoid installing ubuntu 12.04 since I had some bad experiences with this new version.

Cheers,

Lucian

Comment: You can always download the source and compile it http://kile.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: i am not very well versed in compiling stuff in linux so I'd rather not try this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an 11.10 PPA for Kile listed at that PPA, just 12.04, 11.04, 10.10, and 10.04. Not sure why they skipped 11.10. You could attempt adding the PPA for 11.04 or 12.04, but I'm unfamiliar with Kile so I don't know how well that work work or not.

Comment: How do I go about adding a specific ppa? I mean for a specific ubuntu version?

Comment: Edit the file it created in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and change oneiric to either precise or natty

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work there seems to be some dependency issues.

Comment: So then your next options are to either compile, upgrade Ubuntu, or ask the owner of that PPA if they will make an Oneiric build.

Comment: yes i arrived to that conclusion too... unfortunately i had some problems with ubuntu 12.04... it would randomnly log me off while working and all the programs would close so i lost my work a few time. after that i decided to get back to 11.10 because i couldn't find the cause of the crashes (i have been using linux only for about a year now so I don't know much about it).

Comment: It wasn't randomly logging you off, X was crashing. Probably worth looking at ~/.xsession-errors

Comment: I looked at that but there was no info that made any sense to me. I remember once it happened while I was writing a program in mathematica and it logged off so i lost all my work, another time i was trying to download nx client from nomachines and it logged off.